# Spherical shape Galaxy - Is it possible or not?

Tags: space, hard-science, astronomy, galactic

can galaxies exist in spherical form?

If yes, can you tell me how is it possible and whats the size limit of such galaxy

If no, what is the reason it can't form spherical shape?

BONUS: How will you name it?

Comment: It has to do with conservation of angular momentum. This question is better suited for astronomy stakexchange.

Comment: Here it is your answer (and question): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93830/why-the-galaxies-form-2d-planes-or-spiral-like-instead-of-3d-balls-or-spheric

Comment: "Orion's Stone"

Comment: Google 'elliptic galaxies". They're close enough to spherical. This is astronomy plain and simple. So the answer is "yes."

Answer (score 4):

**Reasons for it seeming unlikely:** since it has to be spinning so it has to be squished a bit (so things stick out in the middle). With things preferring to be in this equatorial plane they will pull other things down into the same plane. Like how our solar system is mostly flat.

**However** I looked around and there is actually [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2834.pdf) on just this. Their conclusions are that the it is possible for certain parameters (more detail in the paper). They say:

> We  conclude  that  our  proposed  simple  model  for  spherical
>   galaxy  clusters  leads  to  realistic  radial  profiles  for  all  the  properties of  interest

(Note that this isn't an actual claim that they exist, only that within their assumptions and simple model that it is possible).

They place restrictions on the density of gas compared to the total density, the total mass and radial size. Each different for a particular simulation.

---

In case the link dies the paper is called **A simple parametric model for spherical galaxy clusters** by *Malak Olamaie, Michael P. Hobson and Keith J. B. Grainge* and is probably the fullest answer of your question you'll find.

Comment: Is there a not a distinction here between 'galaxies' and 'galaxy clusters' (which, I thought, were clusters *of* galaxies).

Comment: This isn't correct - a number of galaxies are indeed spherical - and doesn't really answer the question - like @owjburnham said, galaxy clusters aren't galaxies.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely.
Galaxies have a massive, rotating core, which gives the whole thing a preferred axis.

On a smaller scale, globular clusters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globular_cluster are indeed spherical, but they're not galaxies.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Theoretically, the laws of physics allow it. But in the real universe, the probability that such a thing would ever happen is *zero*.

Why not? For the same reason that you never get perfectly circular orbits. There is only one circle, which merely comes in different sizes, but there are infinitely many ellipses. Any old orbital parameters will get you an ellipse of some kind, but you have to get everything just exactly right, forever, to get a circle. Similarly, there is only one sphere, which merely comes in different sizes, but there are infinitely many different ellipsoids. Thus, elliptical galaxies are pretty common, but there are no spherical ones. Such a thing could only happen if it were *somehow* artificially constructed.

Comment: you argument is wrong: we see no galaxies having three dimensional shapes, they are more or less flattened discs with a bulge at their center.  Also, mind that the hard science tag calls for empirical or scientific evidences.

Comment: The question was not if a galaxy can be *perfectly* spherical.

Comment: of course, all galaxies have three dimensional shapes, especially all the [ellipticial galaxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_galaxy). the argument would be then that the odds are low. But the universe is big.